# Output of the HTML page using Chart.js is being rendered blank

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have been working on a big project where I need to get charts displayed on an HTML page.
I am new to JavaScript and was learning about Chart.js from their official site. The output of this code is rendered blank.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.2/chart.js"
        integrity="sha512-mq0l9aRxJmpWp47xw5+DBJ0m2pWg8KBuvGn7nMSia050SC7vjYecudIjApBhd3HvFInxjWZOR3lvT7BZNP7iaw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
    </script>

<body>
<div style= "width: 900px; height: 400px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
  let labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];

  let itemData = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];

  const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        data: itemData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(66, 221, 245)'
    }]
  };

  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data
    };

  const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
    );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am returning the above html using render_template() function from my app.py file.
Unfortunately, though I went through a lot of examples and cross checked my code several times, I couldn't get where I am going wrong. I checked other threads with similar issues, and I am unable to get the solution. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I happened to come across some article which mentioned about issues with different versions of Chart.js. It looks like the latest version is having some issue. I was able to get the charts rendered when I used an older version of Chart.js. 
I randomly selected the version 3.6.0 and voila!!! It worked like a charm.

Comment: The above snippet works fine, except the fact that you have to import from [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) the `umd` version of the chart.js if you're not using modules  ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsgutfLo/)). That is indicated by the browser console error `cannot use import statement outside of module`

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked with the version 4.3.2 of Chart.js.
Thanks a lot @kikon